# What would be the need for more than 2 ground wires in any car, truck, suv, van?

Tags: safety, ground

With the understanding that most all vehicles have at least 2 grounds wires, what items would add to the list of minimum requirements for a safe grounding system.
 An 'item' is defined as an object needing a dedicated ground.
 I have seen as many as 3 - 5 ground wires in one vehicle.
 ALL of these ground wires return to the main battery negative (-) post.
 Please do not answer with something only 'James Bond' would use.

Answer (score 7):

Some sensitive electronic devices need a dedicated ground directly to the battery to cut down on DC line noise, in other words they need a clean as possible DC voltage supply.

Some vehicles do not have easily accessible good grounds, so its an installers choice just to go to the battery.

Other times the installer is not smart enough to find/determine a good ground close to the device, so they run a wire to the battery.

I have installed quite a few of the [FAST fuel injection systems](http://www.fuelairspark.com/fas/efi-systemshtml) on hot rods, and they require both power leads to be connected directly to the battery terminals, and yes it matters if you don't.

Comment: The FAST sounds like something James Bond would like to have...